# Adding multiple rows and saving them using ListView and SimpleAdapter

Tags: android, listview, simpleadapter

For this part, I am trying to create a button that will save data that has been entered into an `EditText` and a Spinner. For now this process does add a single row but everytime i click the button, it will just delete the first row and replace the data. Is there a way I can save multiple rows onto the `ListView`? I am unsure if I have to create multiple arrays for this or if it can be done in an easier way, please let me know. Below is the code I have for the button.

```
//listadapt 
        ListAdapt = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.row, new String[] {"columnone", "columntwo", "columnthree"}, new int[] {R.id.columnone, R.id.columntwo, R.id.columnthree});
//onclick todobutton
        SaveTodo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                map.put("columnone", Add_Item.this.TaskNameET.getText().toString());
                map.put("columntwo", Add_Item.this.SpinType.getSelectedItem().toString());
                map.put("columnthree", Add_Item.this.DateTimeET.getText().toString());
                mylist.add(map);
               MainActivity.getMainList().setAdapter(ListAdapt);
            }
        });
```

Comment: i see where you are comming from but i cant realy understand you.. remove this MainActivity.getMainList().setAdapter(ListAdapt); and replace with context.ListAdapt.notifyDataSetChanged(); and see also post the ListAdapt

Comment: I added the ListAdapt